# Arbitrary Value JsonDiffPatch.net diff function output

Tags: c#, web-scraping

I am trying to find the changed values on website. For that I have written a iterator which will hit the website and get the html output.
I have saved that html output in a json array against country name.

Next time it checks new json value with old json using **JsonDiffPatch**. But **diff** method returns some arbitary value in result.

Output:

```
{{
  "vaccineInfo": [
    "@@ -245,20 +245,8 @@\n ines\n- HELLO World\n %3c/h3\n",
    0,
    2
  ]
}}
```

My C# Code block:

```
var diffObj = new JsonDiffPatch();              
var resultJsonDiff = diffObj.Diff(expected, actual);
List<string> uniqueIndexKeysActual = new List<string>();
foreach (var tempToken in resultJsonDiff)
{
   JObject obj = JObject.Parse("{" + tempToken.ToString() + "}");
   foreach (var pair in obj)
   {
       int outResult = 0;
       if (!uniqueIndexKeysActual.Contains(pair.Key) && int.TryParse(pair.Key, out outResult))
       {
           uniqueIndexKeysActual.Add(pair.Key);
       }
       Console.WriteLine(pair.Key + "," + pair.Value);
   }
}
```

So in `pair.value` I get above output result.

Could anyone help with the same.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By default the library uses google-diff-match-patch to compare string values longer than 50 characters.
You can override this behaviour by passing Options object to JsonDiffPatch constructor.

There are two options:

- change behaviour of string diff by setting TextDiff property
- increase amount of character after which google-diff-match-patch will be used by setting MinEfficientTextDiffLength property

To disable this behavior:

```
var jdp = new JsonDiffPatch(new Options
   {
      TextDiff = TextDiffMode.Simple,
      MinEfficientTextDiffLength = int.MaxValue
   });
```